# TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' in failed test of Restangular call

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, restangular

I'm having a bit of trouble testing an AngularJS controller that is using Restangular to query an API. The test fails with `TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined` which is in reference to the promise returned from Restangular.

I've reproduced the error in plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QGaXeydvOcPg7Ml6qrIK)

I know I'm overlooking something small, but I can't figure out what it is?

Using AngularJS 1.2.5 and Restangular 1.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to resolve the promise again inside your test.

Since it's already been `then()`'d in the controller, you just need to set it to the variable you set in the callback:

```
        resolvedValue = $scope.disaggregators;
```

instead of doing `then()` again.

See updated plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/96CuLhqpCXi3FNgvyOI9)

*note: I hard set the response to match since the api call doesn't work*

Comment: Ok so this changes an assumption I made based on reading a writeup of how to test Restangular based on their github [issue #98](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/98) which is probably for the better. In regards to changing the response though, shouldn't mocking the http request with `httpBackend.expectGet().repsond()` handle this? While the change makes the test pass it breaks the intent of the code to return the result of the Restangular request.

Comment: It still returns the result of the Restangular request, it's just handled in the controller. Before I think you had it trying to resolve twice, once in the controller and again in the test. The mock will handle it, and the promise is resolved in the controller.. I think I may have created confusion by making the test pass.. see [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/i2xFdrWsL6hkIa9ous76)

Comment: That's got it. Still a minor issue with either Restangular's stripRestangular() not removing all of its cruft, but that's a different issue. Thanks!